# Bridge Network Connection VirtualBox 5.1 Ubuntu Headless 16.04

Tags: networking, virtualbox, headless

I'm trying to setup guest virtual machines using virtual Box on a headless ubuntu server using VBoxManage. I have the guest machines running the only issue is with the networking.

Here is the command I used to setup the adapter: enp2s7 is my Ethernet adapter
VBoxManage modifyvm "UbuntuServer" --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 enp2s7

I have installed bridge utils on the host machine also as I thought that was needed.

Here is another thing that I have tried:
Edited on the host machine: /etc/network/innterfaces

> source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
>
> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> ## The primary network interface
>
> auto br0
>
> iface br0 inet static
> address 192.168.1.2
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> network 192.168.1.0
> gateway 192.168.1.1
> dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
> bridge_ports enp2s7
> bridge_fd 0
> bridge_hello 2
> bridge_maxage 0
> bridge_stp off

Then I updated the VM to the following and still it won't connect.

VBoxManage modifyvm "UbuntuServer" --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 br0

This usually pops up during install and even after install I tried to manually configure the interfaces on the Virtual Machine Guest system. The guest system **does** recognize the adapter however it still does not work using both dhcp and static ip.

Any help is appreciated!